# How to run Kotlin + React + Redux using the create-react-kotlin-app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, kotlin, react-redux, jetbrains-ide

I am using the `create-react-kotlin-app` and following the instructions on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app) to create a React + Redux app using Kotlin. The first install part works fine:

```
create-react-kotlin-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

The app works fine, but when I try to add Redux:

```
npm install @jetbrains/kotlin-react-redux

npm WARN @jetbrains/kotlin-extensions@1.0.1-pre.49 requires a peer of core-js@^2.5.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN css-loader@1.0.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN url-loader@1.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @jetbrains/kotlin-react-redux@5.0.7-pre.49 requires a peer of @jetbrains/kotlin-redux@^4.0.0-pre.49 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @jetbrains/kotlin-react-redux@5.0.7-pre.49 requires a peer of react-redux@^5.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @jetbrains/kotlin-react-redux@5.0.7-pre.49
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 5522 packages in 9.891s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Redux doesn't work. How do I fix this? (I am running npm 6.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Hi @divlan Have you tried working through officail [Hands-on](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Building%20Web%20Applications%20with%20React%20and%20Kotlin%20JS/01_Introduction) on Kotlin React App?