# How to run a full stack application using kotlin?

Tags: reactjs, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-js

I want to run a full stack web application with Kotlin + react + reduce. I tried to use the `create-react-kotlin-app` app but [it does not work with reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172898/how-to-run-kotlin-react-redux-using-the-create-react-kotlin-app).

Now I am trying to use the [Thinkter: A Kotlin Full-stack Application Example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-fullstack-sample). I download the zip, unzip it and run:

```
./gradlew backend:run
./gradlew frontend:run
```

When I open the browser (`http://localhost:8080`) I get a blank page and in the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I am using Linux Mint, java version "1.8.0_181" and node v8.12.0.